# how to do junit test else branch of if

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit3

I am trying to do Junit test for the method.

```
  public List<QuestionBank> getQuestionBankDetails(){
            if(stubbed){
                return (List<QuestionBank>) BeanPopulateUtils.getPopulateBeanValues(new QuestionBank(), true);
            }else{
                throw new NotImplementedException("Non-stubbed SOAP call not implemented");
            }
        }
```

This is my Junit case:

```
@Test
    public void testGetQuestionBankDetails(){
        List<QuestionBank> questionBankList = questionBankFacade.getQuestionBankDetails();
        int i=1;
         for(QuestionBank questionBank : questionBankList){
             assertEquals("Name "+i+"", questionBank.getName());
             assertEquals("Description "+i+"", questionBank.getDescription());
             assertEquals("Pubished Status "+i+" ", questionBank.getPubishedStatus());
             assertEquals("Questions "+i+"", questionBank.getQuestions());
             i++;
         }
    }
```

The Junit test case is getting success but the thing i want to ask is how i will test in 'else' case

```
Throw new NotImplementedException("Non-stubbed SOAP call not implemented");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use if it possible interface to differentiate between stubbed and default implementation. And use preferably an configuration logic to "inject" correct behavior, or Factory to generate requested class instance.

See example like this:

BankDetails.class

```
package example;

import java.util.List;

public interface BankDetails {
    List<QuestionBank> getQuestionBankDetails();
}
```

BankDetailsDefaultImpl.class

```
package example;

import java.util.List;

public class BankDetailsDefaultImpl implements BankDetails {

    @Override
    public List<QuestionBank> getQuestionBankDetails() {
        return (List<QuestionBank>) BeanPopulateUtils.getPopulateBeanValues(new QuestionBank(), true);
    }

}
```

BankDetailsStubbedImpl.class

```
package example;

import java.util.List;

public class BankDetailsStubbedImpl implements BankDetails {

    @Override
    public List<QuestionBank> getQuestionBankDetails() {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Non-stubbed SOAP call not implemented");
    }

}
```

QuestionBankFacade.class

```
package example;

public class QuestionBankFacade {

    private final BankDetails bankDetails;

    public QuestionBankFacade(final BankDetails bankDetails) {
        this.bankDetails = bankDetails;
    }

    public BankDetails getQuestionBankDetails() {
        return this.getQuestionBankDetails();
    }

}
```

And finally the JUnit test:

QuestionBankFacadeTest.class

```
package example;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException;
import org.junit.Test;

public class QuestionBankFacadeTest {

    @Test
    public void testDefaultImplementation() {
        final QuestionBankFacade questionBankFacade = new QuestionBankFacade(new BankDetailsDefaultImpl());
        List<QuestionBank> questionBankList = questionBankFacade.getQuestionBankDetails();
        //Test case that you already have
//       for(QuestionBank questionBank : questionBankList){
//             assertEquals("Name "+i+"", questionBank.getName());
//             assertEquals("Description "+i+"", questionBank.getDescription());
//             assertEquals("Pubished Status "+i+" ", questionBank.getPubishedStatus());
//             assertEquals("Questions "+i+"", questionBank.getQuestions());
//             i++;
//         }
    }

    @Test(expected = NotImplementedException.class)
    public void testStubbedImplementation() {
        final QuestionBankFacade questionBankFacade = new QuestionBankFacade(new BankDetailsStubbedImpl());
        questionBankFacade.getQuestionBankDetails();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `stubbed` is a class variable, Create an object and set the variable to false. then call the function `getQuestionBankDetails();`. That way you can check the else part

Answer (score 0):

Due to missing code I assume your `QuestionBankFacade` class looks like this:

```
private boolean stubbed;

public boolean isStubbed() {
    return stubbed;
}

public void setIsStubbed(boolean isStubbed) {
    this.stubbed = isStubbed;
}

public List<QuestionBank> getQuestionBankDetails() {
    if (stubbed) {
        return (List<QuestionBank>) BeanPopulateUtils.getPopulateBeanValues(new QuestionBank(), true);
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("Non-stubbed SOAP call not implemented");
}
```

Than you may write a test like this:

```
@Test(expected=NotImplementedException.class)
public void getQuestionBankDetailsThrowsAnExceptionIfStubbed() {
    boolean memento = questionBankFacade.isStubbed();
    questionBankFacade.setIsStubbed(false);
    try {
        questionBankFacade.getQuestionBankDetails();
    } finally {
        questionBankFacade.setIsStubbed(memento);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a separate test method which will tests the else condition code path.